# Premiere CS4 refuses to import MTS File

Tags: video-editing, adobe-premiere

Working on Adobe Premiere CS4 I'm trying to import `*.MTS` files. Some websites suggest the format is supported, others don't. When I import the files I receive the message:

> File Format not supported.

I've added "new format" support in the past though not for `*.mts` files; how do I add `*.mts` file format support?

Comment: AVCHD was supported in CS4, though may struggle if the full codec pack was not successfully authorised at the time. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/509050 & https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1050730 I'm afraid I can't really help any further, I haven't used CS4 in 10 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why `.mts` wouldn't work in Adobe Premiere CS4.
I have compiled below some of them:

- If this is a trial version of Adobe Premiere CS4, you need the paid version
- Ensure you are running the latest version CS4, since several bugs were fixed
- Sometimes the paid version reverts to trial mode. In that case you will
  need to deactivate and uninstall, run the
  [CS4 Clean Script](https://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cs4clean.html),
  reinstall the latest version and activate. Reboot, then repeat if required.
- I have seen a mention that when opening MTS, you need to pass the folder
  and not a single file, if that helps.

Comment: I'd be careful about clean & reactivate these days. Adobe have basically de-licensed everything older than CC2018, so I'd be wary of the activation servers no longer registering the license. [I have never tested this theory, I'd just be a bit circumspect]